# What causes a MOSFET to short?

Tags: mosfet, oscillator, short-circuit

I'm building a Royer Oscillator, and I'm not sure why my initial MOSFET (U2) is shorting? My LT Spice simulation works somewhat, however I get a lot of current coming out of the drain (6A+), and likewise the 2 inductors drawing massive currents. Why would this be the case?

Is it because of the MOSFETs M1 and M2? Are they what's causing this massive surge in current? And hence the short in the initial MOSFET.

The power supply I'm using is rated to 6A, and it actually goes up to 6A when I turn it on, but the voltage reduces drastically.

Anyone have any ideas? (Ground is the bottom rail).
[image: Royer Oscillator]

Comment: U2 is directly across the power rails.  Each time a pulse turns it on it will short out.

Comment: over-heat and/or over-voltage

Comment: +mkeith , its not that. Its because the 'Fet is directly across the power rails.

Comment: @Alex, use the character '@' to tag people, not +. FET's fail when they get too hot or when they have too high a voltage across channel or at gate. If you can put one across a power supply and turn it on and off without doing either of those things, it will not fail.

Comment: Okay, but I was saying that in this case it was not due to overheating etc.

Comment: @Alex, actually it is due to over-heating. Resistive losses during high pulse current cause excessive heating which causes failure.

Comment: The fet is connected incorrectly, this current instance has nothing to do with overheating etc? I am confused...

Comment: The FET is connected incorrectly. That is why the circuit does not work. But, depending on the current available at the power supply, and how fast the FET is switched, it is not necessarily guaranteed that the FET will fail. FET's can be used to "crowbar" power supplies or blow fuses, or energize heating elements with very low resistance. This is basically a short circuit. The key point is where does the power get dissipated? Some FET's may have Rds on of only 1 or 2 mOhm. A FET like that can actually be placed directly across a fairly large power supply and turned on without being damaged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As HandyHowie told you, you put the Mosfet across the battery.

Look on Fig 1 and 2.
http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irfr4105.pdf

11 V as Vds and 10V as Vgs and the Mosfet will allow ~ 100A,
assuming you battery is capable, a nice 1kW.

The devices will blow up in ~ 100 us. (Zth ~ 0.2 C/W)